# Is it possible to remove a message from the MQ Queue without retriving it or clearing the queue?

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq

I need to clear a group of messages from a MQ Queue, but I need to do this without retriving the message or clearing the whole queue?

Comment: What do you call an "MQ queue"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't remove/clear a message from a queue without retrieving it. A QueueBrowser is used to browse messages from a queue. It does not remove/clear messages from a queue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to use a [QueueBrowser](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html) for this.  The documentation says:

> A client uses a QueueBrowser object to look at messages on a queue without removing them.

[Here's a tutorial](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.mft.samples.mqbrowse.doc/doc/overview.htm) on how to use it for websphere-mq.  [Here's a tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncfm/index.html) on how to use it using just JMS.

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option.
You can use tool,that is called RFH Util.
With this tool you can remove messages, copy queue, etc.
You can download it from here:
ftp://ftp.software.ibm.com/software/integration/support/supportpacs/individual/ih03.zip

Answer (score 0):

Using RFHUtil also, you cant delete particular messages in queue.

You have option to purge queue, which will delete all messages in Queue.